# Git Reverse to Tag and some changes to it and push throw an error

Tags: git, github

We have multiple branches and Tags in Git. I want to make my changes to previous tag and take a new tag out of it. To do that I use

1) `Git reset --hard <tagname>`

Did some changes to the files

2) `git commit`

When I am trying to Push my changes it says

```
 failed to push some refs to ""
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Any quick help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to undo shared commits. You can push your modified branch anyway by forcing:

```
git push -f <remote_repo_name> <branch_name>
```

BUT, this is very bad if the branch you're editing has already been used by other developers and merged into other branches

Answer (score 1):

With `git reset --hard <commit-ish>` you repoint your current branch to the given commit. If you then want to push this branch, it of course says you should not do this as you are rewriting history.

What you probably wanted to do is

```
git checkout <tag>
// do work
git commit -m 'foo'
git tag foo
git push origin foo
```